# Is there a way to get a operations/change log when a pandas does a bulk operation?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I work with dataframes in Jupyter Notebooks w/pandas, I can do great bulk operations, for example:

```
df_color_pallette.loc[df_color_pallette['foreground']=='red','foreground']='green'
```

To change every entry in the 'foreground' column from 'red' to 'green'.  However, if I want to know which entries were changed, or even just how many changes were made, I would have to, for example, keep a copy of the column as "before" and compare it to the changed column (and yes, I've done that).  But that seems very inefficient, forcing at least 2 passes through the data.  Are they any pandas hooks/logs/flags that have that information?

Comment: Oops.   Misspelled palette in my example.  I hate when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the mask

```
mask = df_color_pallette['foreground'] == 'red'

df_color_pallette.loc[mask, 'foreground'] == 'green'
```

Then check

```
mask.sum()
```

Or even change again

```
df_color_pallette.loc[mask, 'foreground'] == 'beige'
```

Comment: That occurred to me and is a good approach, but loses the appeal of those one-liners!   I will probably adopt that as standard coding pattern, and tag this as answer after the question percolates a little.

Comment: Having a one-liner and keeping track of changes efficiently are at odds.  Also, I'd advise against a desire for one-liners.  They often lead to obscure and unreadable code.